# Custom Malloc in C - segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make the malloc() function using best-fit allocation. I used a doubly linked list to implement data structures of the memory blocks.

Each block is composed of header and data. But my program keeps giving me a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I run it.

Part of my code is as follows:

```
typedef struct Node{ 
    unsigned int size; 
    int flag; // free is 1 and used is 0
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev; 
}Node;

Node* head = NULL;
Node* tail = NULL;

Node* find_best_fit(unsigned int size){
    size += sizeof(Node);
    Node* curr;
    curr = head;
    Node* best_fit = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL){
        if((curr->flag) && (curr->size >= size) && (best_fit == NULL || curr->size < best_fit->size)){
            best_fit = curr;
            if(best_fit->size == size){
                break;
            }
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return best_fit;
}


void* my_malloc(unsigned int size)
{
    if(size == 0)
        return NULL;

    Node* best = NULL;
    Node* current_node = NULL;
    Node* temp_node = NULL;
    Node* rem = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = (Node*)sbrk(size + sizeof(Node));
        head->flag = 0;
        head->prev = NULL;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->size = size;
        tail = head;
        return (head + sizeof(Node));
    } else{
        best = find_best_fit(size);
        if(best == NULL){
            current_node = (Node*)sbrk(size + sizeof(Node));
            temp_node->prev = tail;
            temp_node->next = NULL;
            temp_node->size = size + sizeof(Node);
            temp_node->flag = 0;
            current_node = temp_node;
            tail->next = current_node;
            tail = current_node;
            return (void*)(current_node + sizeof(Node));
        } else{
            current_node = (Node*)(best+size);
            rem->size = best->size - size - sizeof(Node);
            rem->flag = 1;
            rem->next = best->next;
            rem->prev = best;
            current_node = rem;
            current_node->next->prev = current_node;
            best->size = size + sizeof(Node);
            best->flag = 0;
            best->next = current_node;
            return (void*)(best + sizeof(Node));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried debugging?

Comment: Run valgrind on your program

Comment: Also you do not check if `sbrk(2)` fails.

Comment: what do you mean for sbrk(2)

Comment: `sbrk(2)` is a notation for the `sbrk` function from section 2 (system calls) of the Unix manual

Comment: Note that the dot (`.`) and arrow (`->`) operators bind very tightly and should never be written with spaces around them.

Comment: Your code formatting is weird — to be polite about it.  Please post sanely indented code.

Comment: You've got alignment problems with `size + sizeof(Node)`.  Maybe you'll get away with poor performance, but on many machines, you'd get bus errors for misaligned data access.